# Excel Instance Parsing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of data "instances" within one column within an excel sheet.

Each instance *can* have numerous copies. Here is an example:

```
abcsingleinstanceblah0001
cdemultipleinstanceexample0001
cdemultipleinstanceexample0002
cdemultipleinstanceexample0003
cdemultipleinstanceexample0004
....
```

Unfortunately the numbering scheme was not preserved across all of this data. So in some cases copies will have randomized numbers. However, the root instance name is always the same.

**QUESTION:** What would be a good strategy for creating a function that will parse a list of these instances and, in a new column, list all duplicates past the second copy? In relation to the example above, the new column would list:

```
cdemultipleinstanceexample0003
cdemultipleinstanceexample0004
```

I need to have the two duplicates with the lowest integer values preserved out of each set of duplicates, which is why in the example above 3 and 4 would have to go. So in the case of randomized numbers, the two instances with the lowest integer values.

**What I have thought of**

I was thinking to first organize the column by alphabetical order, which should automatically put duplicates in ascending order. I could then basically strip the number value from all instances, and find where there are more than 2 exact duplicates from the core instance name, which would give me the instances with more than 2 duplicates so that I could perform a function on the original data set... but I don't know if there is a better way of doing this or where to go from here.

I'm looking for formula-based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sorted list is in Column A and that you have a row of headers you could use the following formulas in the neighboring columns.

In B:
        =LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-4)

In C (although not really necessary):
        =RIGHT(A2,4)

In D starting with row 3:
        =IF(AND(B3=B2,COUNTIF(B1:B3,B3)>2),"Del","Keep")

This formula doesn't work in row 2, but you can hard code the first result.

Then filter the list on Column D for "Del" and delete all the rows.

How's that?

Answer (score 0):

Sort your list in column A.  You'll want column headings for later so put those in row 1 (or leave it blank.  In `B2`, type `=left(A2,len(A2)-4)` and drag the formula down to strip the integers.  In `C3` type `=vlookup(B3,$B$2:$B2,1,0)`.  Populate the formula in `C3` right one cell and then down the length of the data.  Now in D3 you'll have a list that has errors for any entry that only 2 or fewer instances and will have the name for any that have 2 or more.  Sorting this list with a filter on row D for #NA will allow you to delete all the rows with less than two entries.

Remove your filter.  Then resort the list in column A in reverse order so the high numbers are first.  Replace the contents of C2 and D2 with #N/A.  Refilter the list on column D for everything but #N/A and delete all the entries that have an instance listed.